# How do I create a strong 64 bit number?

Tags: random, 64-bit

Does anyone know how I can create a method that generates a random 64 bit number (0 to 2^63 - 1)  that is converted to a character string?

Thanks

Comment: like a Base64 random String generator ?

Comment: What do you mean by "strong"?

Answer (score 0):

In C# you might try something like this:

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[64];
Random rnd = new Random();
rnd.NextBytes(bytes);
var str64 =  Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
```